# Apache Mesos on Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, mesos

I am trying to install Apache Mesos from this link : http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/

I did it for first time was stuck on this step :

```
# Start mesos master (Ensure work directory exists and has proper permissions).
$ ./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=127.0.0.1 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
```

The error raised was :

```
    vivek@Pavilion-dv6:~/mesos/build$ ./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=127.0.0.1 --work_dir = /var/lib/mesos
   ./bin/mesos-master.sh: line 24: /home/vivek/mesos/build/src/mesos-master: No such file or directory
```

I have deleted the directory and willing to start again to install but as Homepage says, it works on  64 bit Ubuntu , I have Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit. Should I go on and try again or Should get 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32bit OSes are not officially supported. You may try to build Mesos from sources (and then report the result on the Mesos dev list) or switch to a 64bit OS. Any VM will do.

Comment: switching to 64 bit OS .